# Odata Open Type and Odata Client Library

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a business requirement where I need to expose set of custom properties defined by user and since this is user configuration, I cannot go away by creating classes. Therefore I need to opt for open types feature in Odata.

Q1. Is there any sample implementation out there on how I can persist the data to database and also support the querying capabilities on open types?

Q2. One issue I noticed is currently client library is not correctly handling open types and can only be achieved by partial classes that means user has to know the custom properties up front so that they can hand craft partial classes which is not what I want to do. Instead better approach would have been to support open types on client side by dynamic properties. Any pointers on how the client side experience can be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

About query capabilities on open types, order and filter is supported in v5.5(will be released by the end of this month), query the value of dynamic properties, you can follow this [pull request](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/pull/222), part of this is in master branch now.

About persist the data to database, I think you can consider non-relational database, which can be a good choice for your open type data.

About Q2, achieve by dynamic properties is not implement in client library, maybe you can open an issue in [github](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues) for us.